# error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)' MAMP

Tags: mysql, сервер, mamp

Скачал `MAMP`, вбиваю в терминале:

```
./mysqladmin -u root -  password "newpassword"
```

и выдает это ошибку error:

```
'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'
```

Что делать?

Comment: не работал с `mysqladmin`, на вскидку - а пробел разве нужен перед `password`? и там точно `-password`? может `-p`?

Comment: слитно пишется -p и слитно с ним же пароль т.е. -pпароль или просто -p без доп параметров и пароль оно отдельно спросит (так в принципе безопасней, пароль в логах команд не останется)

Comment: я делал по книге и там написано было как я написал, сейчас попробую по вашему

Comment: а имя пользователя в бд для соединения написано правильно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Утилиты MySQL позволяют задать пароль аккаунта при помощи параметра `--password` или его краткой формы `-p`. В полной форме, если вы не указываете пароль, он запрашивается у вас отдельно

```
./mysqladmin -u root --password
```

Вы можете указать пароль в командной строке, через =

```
./mysqladmin -u root --password=newpassword
```

В краткой форме параметра `-p`, без указания пароля, пароль будет запрошен сразу после выполнения команды

```
./mysqladmin -u root -p
```

Или вы можете указать его сразу после параметра введя его **без пробела и дополнительных символов**

```
./mysqladmin -u root -pnewpassword
```

Однако, указывать пароль в командной строке считается дурным тоном, так как команда остается в логах, которые в случае взлома могут быть использованы злоумышленником для увеличения привилегий. Если использование пароля в команде необходимо, можно предварить команду пробелом

```
$ ./mysqladmin -u root -pnewpassword
```

В этом случае она не попадет в историю. Однако, на практике чаще прибегают локальному конфигурационному файлу пользователя ~/.my.cnf, в котором указывают предпочтительный логин и пароль, выставляя права доступа на него таким образом, чтобы прочитать его мог только владелец.

```
[client]
user=root
password=newpassword
```